# Как найти нужный "элемент" в массиве jsonb?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Есть таблица table2, в ней есть столбец data, который является jsonb. В нем такая структура:

```
{
  "jsonb": {
    "ver": 0
  },
  "info": [
     {
     "name": "Ivan",
     "isMain": false
     },
     {
     "name": "Denis",
     "isMain": true
     },
     {
     "name": "Dima",
     "isMain": false
     }
  ],
}
```

Я делаю запрос к какой-то таблице table1, join-ом соединяю ее с table2, и пытаюсь достать какие-то значения из обоих таблиц (обычным select-ом). Но мне нужно как-то из этого jsonb поля достать name, который соответствует isMain = true, то есть нужно получить Denis. Как это можно сделать? Я пытаюсь придумать что-то, связанное с таким вариантом, но ничего не получается:

```
select tbl1.id,
       jsonb_array_elements(tbl2.data -> 'info' ->> 'name') as main_name (но не понимаю, куда вставлять условие)
   from table1 tbl1
      join table2 tbl2 on tbl1.id = tbl2.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете попробовать использовать следующий код. Прошу дать знать если он вам помог!

```
SELECT tbl1.id, main_info->>'name' AS main_name
FROM table1 tbl1
JOIN table2 tbl2 ON tbl1.id = tbl2.id
CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT jsonb_array_elements(tbl2.data->'info') AS main_info
    WHERE main_info->>'isMain' = 'true'
) subquery;
```